# Exception at startup: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'wss:binding'

Tags: spring, binding, wss, applicationcontext

I am starting a JBoss server in Eclipse and during startup this is the error appearing:

```
JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 12 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 28; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'wss:binding'.
```

This is the applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core"
    xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">

    <wss:binding url="/atsws">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#atsWs" />
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>

    <!-- Web service methods -->
    <bean id="atsWs" class="com.ats.ws.HelloWorldWS">
        <property name="helloWorldBo" ref="HelloWorldBo" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="HelloWorldBo" class="com.ats.ws.HelloWorldBoImpl" />
</beans>
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this one. It was a combination of maven dependency changes and using the right schema for the version of jaxws-spring. Unfortunately, I could not get the current versions of jaxws-spring and xbean-spring to work on my project due to version conflicts.

This solution runs on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 server. Here is what I solved the problem with:

POM file dependnecies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion> 
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId> 
        </exclusion> 
        <exclusion> 
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId> 
        </exclusion> 
        <exclusion> 
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId> 
        </exclusion> 
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
        <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

The web service config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
       xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd">         
    <wss:binding url="/ws">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#webService"/>
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>
    <bean id="webService" class="project.LegislativeCalendar">
        <property name="calendaringService" ref="calendaringService"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Hope this helps. Better late then never, right?